# How do we change the value of a variable based on another variable?

Tags: xslt

I have two variables named **editable** and **display**.

If the value of **editable** is `true`, I want to set the value of **display** to `'block'`.

If the value of **editable** is `false`, I want to set the value of **display** to `'none'`.

This is what I have currently:

```
   <xsl:param name="editable" select="true()"/>
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$editable">
         <xsl:variable name="display" select="'block'"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:variable name="display" select="'none'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
```

The code above doesn't set the value of `display` to `none`.

How do we change the value of a variable based on another variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test this, but for me it looks like a problem of scope which might be solved this way:

```
   <xsl:param name="editable" select="true()"/>
   <xsl:variable name="display">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$editable">
            <xsl:value-of select="'block'"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'none'"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: You don't need `<xsl:value-of>` to get a constant string, you can just write `<xsl:when test='$editable'>block</xsl:when>`. Just note that whatever whitespace you put in there will survive.

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig . btw is this ok: `<xsl:text>block</xsl:text>` ?

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig: yes, I know; but I wanted to keep it near to the original example, where one can easily exchange 'block' or 'non' against any xpath function.

Comment: @Pacerier: Sure. `<xsl:text>` only exists to avoid the whitespace issues.